# compare dates in javascript not working

Tags: javascript

Why is below code  for comparing dates in java script  is not working.

```
var fromdate=document.getElementById(attendanceFromDate_txt).value;
alert(fromdate);
var val123=document.getElementById(attendanceToDate_txt).value;

var check = new Date(fromdate) ;
var check123 = new Date(val123) ;

if (check < check123) {
    alert("Please enter from date less than to date") ;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: In which format you are inserting date into the textbox ? Post your html code also your error message seems wrong here because if(fromdate < todate) satisfy's then Entered from and to date is correct one.If condition not satisfy then you have to give message like 'Please enter from date less than to date'

Comment: @SatyamKoyani looks like user input :/ yikes. There are very specific formats in which you need to specify the date being passed as an argument to Date() constructor OP. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: try Date.parse like this new Date(Date.parse(fromdate));

Answer (score 0):

I think that you miss `" "` in `document.getElementById(attendanceFromDate_txt).value;` 
Edit it: `document.getElementById("attendanceFromDate_txt").value;`